# Does PostgreSQL automatically detect unique records in group by clause?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Is it not mandatory in PostgreSQL to add unique column into group by clause?

I usually use Microsoft SQL Server in which we have to add all needed column into group by clause.

PostgreSQL query :

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_invoice_detail;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_invoice_detail(
    invoice_id integer,
    item_id integer,
    qty integer,
    warehouse_id integer    
);

ALTER TABLE temp_invoice_detail ADD CONSTRAINT temp_invoice_detail_result_pkey PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, item_id);

insert into temp_invoice_detail (invoice_id, item_id, qty, warehouse_id) values (1, 1, 100, 1);
insert into temp_invoice_detail (invoice_id, item_id, qty, warehouse_id) values (1, 2, 200, 1);
insert into temp_invoice_detail (invoice_id, item_id, qty, warehouse_id) values (2, 1, 100, 1);

select invoice_id, item_id, sum(qty) as total_qty, warehouse_id
from temp_invoice_detail
group by invoice_id, item_id --should I add "warehouse_id" in group by clause?
order by invoice_id, item_id;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_invoice_detail;
```

I expect PostgreSQL display error message:

> column "temp_invoice_detail.warehouse_id" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function

But the query runs successfully and returns 3 records (all 3 records in insert statement above).

```
invoice_id  item_id  total_qty  warehouse_id
1           1        100        1
1           2        200        1
2           1        100        1
```

In MS-SQL, for this query can run without error, the group by clause have to be:

> group by invoice_id, item_id, warehouse_id

Comment: Which value of the `warehouse_id` do you expect for each `(invoice_id, item_id)` group?  Answering this question and writing a proper ANSI compliant query is the best thing to do here.

Comment: This is only example query. I only confuse why this query not produce the error message that "I have to add warehouse_id in group by clause, because it's not included in aggretate function (i.e : SUM)". I edited the question so warehouse_id only have 1 value to be more obvious. Anyway, by ANSI compliant query do you mean I "better" add warehouse_id into group by clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you defined `invoice_id, item_id` to be the primary key of the table and grouping by the unique key is enough, as adding more columns to the group won't change the outcome of the group by.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the **ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) **are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

This is actually allowed by the SQL standard. Postgres even goes so far to *remove* unneeded columns (based on the existence of primary or unique keys) from the group by, because that improves performance.